# Underscore JS Not Loading

Tags: javascript

I am writing code that uses Underscore JS in Drupal 9 that should be loaded from /core/assets/vendor/underscore.

I am using Chrome DevTools to see the sources and though jquery, jquery-once, and modernizer are all loading from /core/assets/vendor/ the underscore library is not.

I am almost positive that this was working last week. I have updated my code since then but it is the same use of underscore. I do this in Drupal 8 and it works for sure.

I have cleared the cache multiple times. I have verified that the files for underscore are in my filesystem.

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: You have to load a library that is dependent on this. If not, it doesn't matter if the files exist, they won't load unless called or depended on by library definitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the library was not loaded by the theme in my case I needed to do a form alter and then load the library. You can use something like this:

```
    //Load JS
    $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/underscore';
    $form['#attached']['library'][] = 
           'my_module/my_forms.js';
}
```

If you are adding your own library will need to define that in my_module.libraries.yml. Something like this:

```
my_module.js:
  js:
    js/my_forms.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jQuery
    - core/underscore
```

Hope this helps.